# same padding around dynamic list and remove padding from first and last row

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i need to create a dynamic list with equal paddings around each li.
The issue that i don't know how to fix is multiple padding around list item next to each other.
so if one element has 30px padding, then the space  between the next element will be 60px (30px for each element). i need it to be 30px.

My biggest problem is that i don't want top padding for the first row because i want the list to be close the the title.

I'm using responsive design and the list will be load dynamically. so i don't know how many list items will be and how many rows.

this is what i want to achieve [image]

This fiddle is not the best (list_item supposed to be 33.3%) - http://jsfiddle.net/urjzsr73/1/

```
    <div style="background: green; height: 70px"></div>
<div class="list_container">
    <ul>
        <li class="list_item">
            <div class="item_container">a
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list_item">
            <div class="item_container">a
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list_item">
            <div class="item_container">a
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list_item">
            <div class="item_container">a
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list_item">
            <div class="item_container">a
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list_item">
            <div class="item_container">a
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list_item">
            <div class="item_container">a
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="background: green; height: 70px"></div>
```

css:

```
.list_container{
    background: yellow;
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.list_item{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32.9%;
    padding: 3%

}

.item_container{
    background: green;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;

}
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS here? because JSFiddle doesn't work

Comment: i added the css to the question. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Add 1.5% padding on all items

2) Remove the 1.5% padding from the items on the top, lhs and rhs with `nth-child`

```
/* first three items */
.list_item:nth-child(-n + 3){
    padding-top: 0;
}
/* items on the left */
.list_item:nth-child(3n + 1){
    padding-left: 0;
}
/* items on the right */
.list_item:nth-child(3n){
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

3) To remove the bottom padding - just add a negative margin to the `ul`

```
ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 0 3%;
    margin-bottom: -3%; /* <-- */
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/urjzsr73/3/)**

Comment: i don't know how many items will be at the end of the list. this is dynamic list. the last row can be with only one item.